# Excel: Applying functions to a range of ranges using multi-cell array-formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

#### Can you apply a builtin function that takes a range (e.g. AVERAGE()), and have it apply to a multiple ranges?

I'm currently finishing up a pretty basic data-analysis unit with a small Excel segment and I had a past assignment that involved analysing some housing data.

One task involved averaging and rounding the residential housing prices of a few cities for each time period.

The target data is in the worksheet `Residential_Houses`, formatted such that cities are columns and time periods are rows spanning: `C7:J30`. With the goal to have the averages of each row in the worksheet `Analysis` spanning `C7:C30`.

My simple solution was to write the formula:

```
=ROUND(AVERAGE(Residential_Houses!C7:J7), 2)
```

Into `Analysis!C7` and then used Excel's "AutoFill" feature to generate the formulae for `Analysis!C8:C30`. This worked fine, and the results were correct but I lost marks for not explicitly using cell array formula.

Instead the sample answer I was given was this monolithic line:

```
{=ROUND((Residential_Property!C7:C30+Residential_Property!D7:D30+Residential_Property!E7:E30+Residential_Property!F7:F30+Residential_Property!G7:G30+Residential_Property!H7:H30+Residential_Property!I7:I30+Residential_Property!J7:J30)/8,2)}
```

It seems clear that the intent of this code is to take the average of columns C-J for each row 7-30, but it avoids using the AVERAGE() builtin. This works, but it's cumbersome, and wouldn't scale if there were more than a few columns in this test data.

The crux of my question here is how can you combine **functions** that already operate **on ranges**, with **cell array formula** to process multiple ranges with a single formula?

My intuition tells me it might be something like this:

```
{=AVERAGE((C7:J7):(C30:J30))}
```

Or something involving indirect addressing, but I can't seem to find any detailed information on the topic. All of the array formula resources I've found so far have been limited to basic arithmetic and single dimension ranges. Could someone point me in the right direction here, or is this just not possible with array formula?

**EDIT**: For anyone who stumbles upon this in the future. I chose Barry's solution because it helped me understand how to generalise this concept (replacing the range with a function that can slice a range). But as Scott notes, OFFSET() is volatile; so INDEX() is a better way to do this if you're working with large datasets.

Comment: Hey Jesse: What course is this? I'm curious to see what else they cover. Personal interest only...nothing directly related to your question.

Comment: @jeffreyweir The unit is CITS2401 - Computer Analysis and Visualisation at the University of Western Australia. It's primarily MATLAB focused, and honestly I think it's quite a poor unit. It's aimed at second-level engineering students with no prior programming experience so it's *very* barebones. It's a bit disappointing for a CompSci/DataSci major.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to Scott's suggestion, `SUBTOTAL` can process an array of ranges created by an `OFFSET` function, so with the first argument of `SUBTOTAL` as 1 (for `AVERAGE`) this formula will give an array of rounded averages for each row

`=ROUND(SUBTOTAL(1,OFFSET(C7:J30,ROW(C7:J30)-ROW(C7),0,1)),2)`

entered in a vertical range and confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

or you can use the same `OFFSET` inside an `AVERAGE` function like this:

`=ROUND(AVERAGE(OFFSET(C7:J30,ROW(C7:J30)-ROW(C7),0,1)),2)`

Comment: Thanks for this. This really helped me understand what I need to do to generalise it.

The key thing I was missing was that I need a function that will "slice" a single range from a larger range, i.e.: OFFSET() or INDEX(). That slicing function will be the part that will produce multiple ranges when used in an appropriate array formula, and then the range consuming function (in this case AVERAGE()) can then operate on those ranges as normal.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a formula that can be entered as one array formula and get results.  It can also be entered normally and copied down.

```
=ROUND(AVERAGE(INDEX($C$7:$J$30,ROW()-MIN(ROW($C$7:$J$30))+1,0)),2)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a really helpful answer, but I went with Barry's because it's slightly more readable and explicit. Thanks!

Comment: @JesseWyatt just so you know OFFSET is volatile and is why I suggest INDEX which is not.

Comment: Oh, that's surprising. Thanks for the heads up, I assumed if anything that INDEX would also be volatile. I'll do a bit more reading and maybe change it back.

Comment: @JesseWyatt see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396